# Administrating System Center with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'd like to use more powershell when dealing with SCCM 2012. Specifically, I'd like to be able to query clients in a collection for their individual MAC addresses. As of right now, I have to go through each of my device collections -> show members -> right click, then properties.

With the information being available graphically, I'd like to know if I could access it via "Connect with Windows PowerShell" to make collecting it much easier.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question as stated in the [Help/on-topic] but more of a feature request or Wish List.

Answer (score 1):

The CM12 module doesn't provide MACAddresses as far as I know. You could use WMI to get them. Ex:

```
function Get-CMMACFromCollection ($SiteServer, $Site, $CollectionID) {

    $query = "SELECT sys.NetbiosName, sys.MacAddresses FROM SMS_R_SYSTEM sys, SMS_FullCollectionMembership fcm WHERE sys.ResourceID = fcm.ResourceID AND fcm.CollectionID = '$collectionid'"

    Get-WmiObject -Query $query -Namespace "root\sms\site_$site" -ComputerName $siteserver | Select-Object NetbiosName, MACAddresses
}

Get-CMMACFromCollection -SiteServer "server1" -Site "A01" -CollectionID "A0100121"
```